# Deducting type depending on size C++

Tags: c++, types, size

is it possible to choose type depending on size in compile time?

Not working prototype would be

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct Bigger 
{
    using type = (sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)) ? T : U;  
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `std::conditional_t` can be used as a compile-time "conditional operator":

```
using type = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)), T, U>;
```